# How to vertically center the bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to this.Actually, I have tried all the solutions which are there ,  So, I am asking this question.

My model css is

```
#orphanModal{
  .modal-body{
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .modal-dialog{
    width: 700px;
  }
  .modal-close, .modal-close:hover{
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .modal-header{
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

My model is the default one which we take from bootstarp site .
can any one please tell me what is wrong with my css ?

I tried

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

as well. but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hiskj check this out

Comment: I am using this:

https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/pen/mKfCc

and it works for me.

Comment: which bootstrap version are u using?

Comment: Your code is working..fine..https://jsfiddle.net/hLqn76c5/2/ . Please create a snippet of your code to make the issue evitable.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3 is the version

Answer (score 0):

To verticaly align anything, modal in this case you can do this:

```
.modal{
  position: relative;
  top: 50;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

> Notice: This will work if parent element have position relative.

And this will align element when you resize also.